# Modificacion de codigo Matriz

Tags: java, eclipse

Tengo el siguiente método que toma un array y multiplica elemento a elemento por K y retorna el arreglo multiplicado

```
   static int[] multiplicarArray(int[] arr, int k) {
        int[] nuevo = new int[arr.length];
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
            nuevo[i]=arr[i]*k;
        }
        return nuevo;   
    }
```

Y este otro método que toma una matriz, un array y un entero y devuelve true o false si el arreglo pasado por parámetro multiplicado elemento a elemento por K pertenece a una columna de la matriz

```
 public static boolean existeColumnaMultiploK(int[][] mat, int[] vec, int k) {
        int[] nuevo = multiplicarArray(vec, k); //nuevo toma el arreglo multiplicado
        int contador = 0;
            
        for (int c = 0; c < mat[0].length; c++) {
            for (int f = 0; f < mat.length; f++) {
                if(contador == vec.length) 
                    return true;
                if(nuevo[f] == mat[f][c]) 
                    contador++;
                else 
                    contador = 0;
            }   
        }    
        return (contador == vec.length);
    }
```

El ejercicio estaría resuelto pero lo que quisiera es realizar una  modificación, es decir, realizarlo pero sin los IF en el código, que en vez de tener IF tenga variables booleanas que se vayan actualizando en lo que se van comparando. Creo que debería de plantearlo de otra manera pero no me estaría saliendo la modificación. ¿Podríais orientarme con alguna idea?

Comment: Hablas de cambiar el contador por una variable booleana? Y en cada comprobación ir actualizándola eso?

Answer (score 4):

Puedes usar el operador logico "and" cuyo simbolo es "&&" para comparar los numeros del arreglo con el de la matriz usando una variable booleana de esta forma:

```
public boolean existeColumnaMultiploK(int[][] mat, int[] vec, int k) {
    int[] nuevo = multiplicarArray(vec, k); // nuevo toma el arreglo multiplicado
    boolean band = true;

    for (int c = 0; c < mat[0].length; c++) {
        band = true;
        for (int f = 0; f < mat.length; f++) {
            band = band && (nuevo[f] == mat[f][c]);
        }
        if (band)
            break;
    }
    return band;
}
```

Al iniciar cada columna se debe hacer true la variable de lo contrario no sera una iteracion de cada columna sino que tomaria el resultado de la columna anterior. Al finalizar el ciclo de cada columna se usa un if para saber si la variable termina en true, de esa forma se sabe si el arreglo es igual a la columna. Espero que sea una respuesta que esperabas, saludos.